# How to remove typescript template from create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I had full intentions to use typescript in my react project, so I started with the cmd `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and now I would like to remove it.

Any ideas without having to use the standard create-react-app and moving everything over?

Comment: Delete the project and create a new one?

Comment: This is gonna sound blunt, but literally create a new project, copy your TS code, then proceed to delete the TypeScript specific syntax until you have no more syntax errors (and also delete the tsconfig).

Comment: No worries, I’ll give that a go, just wondered if anyone knew any simple trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Recently downloaded a react project from github which didn't use typescript. It was broken due to react-native coming with typescript. Removed typescript in three steps

1. renamed app.tsx to app.js
2. deleted tsconfig.json file
3. opened terminal and ran `npm uninstall typescript`

After these three things I was able to remove typescript from my react project and ran normally.